# Play video(embed) inside Webview

Tags: android, video, webview

I'm trying to play a video inside the `webview`. I have video embed url. The video embed can be from diffrent sources. I checked in many suggestions, but none of them worked fro me. I even tried by passing entire `<iframe>` to the webview. But still it's not working. But when I set the entire webview url, it loads. Why it's not working with the video embed url. Below is my code:

```
public void showEmbedinWebview(String embedUrl) {
        if (getActivity() != null && embedUrl != null) {
            FrameLayout videoContainer = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
            videoContainer.setLayoutParams(UiUtils.getLayoutParams());
            setContainerId(videoContainer);
            mTextviewContainer.addView(videoContainer);
            VideoEnabledWebView vWebview = new VideoEnabledWebView(getActivity());
            vWebview.setLayoutParams(UiUtils.getLayoutParams());
            setWebViewId(vWebview);
            vWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            vWebview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            vWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

            vWebview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
            vWebview.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
            videoContainer.addView(vWebview);
            vWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                    showProgressBar();

                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    hideProgressBar();
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                }

                @Override
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                    Toast.makeText(mActivity, mActivity.getResources().getString(R.string.no_network_msg), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
                }

                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                    return false;
                }
            });

            if (embedUrl != null) {
                vWebview.loadUrl(embedUrl);
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of playing video in webview use VideoView.**

This is the code for playing video in videoview.

```
            videoview video=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoview);

            video.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
            mc.setAnchorView(video);
            mc.setMediaPlayer(video);
            url = url.replace(" ", "%20");
            Log.e("url",url);
            Uri videoLInk = Uri.parse(url);
            video.setMediaController(mc);
            video.setVideoURI(videoLInk);
            video.requestFocus();
            video.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    video.start();
                }
            });
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I'm already using Videoview, to play video embeds. Just in case, if I'm not able to get the exact video url, then in such cases, I'm using webview . And to the webview, i'm passing video embed url, not the mp4 video url

Comment: In videoview you can also pass url which does not have any type extension like .mp4 or . 3gp.

Comment: does it give any mediaplayer error in logcat? These because i am using videoview for playing video which does not have any type of estenstion and it played like a charm.